# What is this c++ program not executing?

Tags: c++

I am testing the concept of putting classes in separate files for the first time and while executing getting an error. Please help

**main.cpp**   this is the main file

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "newClass.h"
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       newClass obj1("mayan");
      cout << obj1.doneName() << endl ;


    }
```

**newClass.h** this is the separate header file

```
#ifndef NEWCLASS_H
#define NEWCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string>
class newClass{

private:
    string name;

public:
    newClass(string z) ;

     string doneName();

};


#endif // NEWCLASS_H
```

and this is the separate **newClass.cpp** file

```
#include "newClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
newClass::newClass(string z)
{
   name = z ;
}

 string newClass :: doneName()
 {
     return name;
 }
```

Comment: It's not executing a lot of things. But do you mean it's not compiling, or not linking, or not running how you want it?

Comment: In the header file change `string` to `std::string`

Comment: I mean its showing an error.

Comment: MM could you please modify it for me? I do not get where to put that std::string

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read more about C++ and its [compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work). Read more about the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)).

Notice that a C++ source file is a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) and usually [includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) some header files. Read more about the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

You'll better use `std::string` not just `string`  in a header file (because having `using std;`  is frowned upon in header files).

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`.

In practice, you'll better use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) when building a project with several translation units.

Remember that [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s are just glorified [source code editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) able to run external tools like build automation tools, compilers, debuggers, version control systems, etc... You'll better be able to use these tools on the command line.